# Java: how to turn local references created in for loop into global references?

Tags: java

How to create local references created in for loop into global references?   The following code wont compile:

Also, in real project, the number of t's and type of t's are data driven (I'm looping through a map of maps to make decision), so I cannot specify t before starting for loop.....

```
public class TestLocal{
  public static void main(String [] args){

  for (int i=1; i<1; i++){
    TestLocal t=new TestLocal();
   }
   System.out.println("This is the new object:  " + t );
 }
}
```

How could I make t accessible from outside for loop?

**more code**

Note:

1)test has many values, and what instance to create depends on its value.

2) since I'm looping through a map of maps which are data driven, the number of instances to be created depend on the number of inner maps......

```
                        for (int i=0;i<sortedMap.size();i++){
                           ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>(sortedMap.keySet());
                           Object o=a.get(i);
                           HashMap m=(HashMap)sortedMap.get(o);
                           int test = ((Number)m.get("textType")).intValue();
                          if (test==3){
                           System.out.println("all together: " + sortedMap.size() + "each element is:  " + o + " value: " + m.get("textType"));
                           String mytest = (String)m.get("text");
                           ChapterAutoNumber chapter1 = new ChapterAutoNumber(mytest);
                        }
```

Comment: not the _whole_ code.. just the relevant bits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "local reference" or a "global reference". You're just trying to access a variable without it being in scope. You want something like:

```
TestLocal t = null;
for (int i=1; i<1; i++) {
    TestLocal t=new TestLocal();
}
System.out.println("This is the new object:  " + t );
```

Note that this will print `null` though, because you're not actually going to run the loop body (because 1 is not less than 1).

If you want to collect the objects created in the loop, a list may be more appropriate:

```
List<TestLocal> list = new ArrayList<TestLocal>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(new TestLocal());
}
// Now access the objects via list
```

Comment: Thank you, Jon!  The problem is that the number of my t as well as the type of t's are data driven....I need to loop through a map of maps to decide how many t's needed and what types of t I need to create.....

Comment: @john: Well if you're creating several instances, it sounds like you'll definitely need a collection of some form, as per my second example. If you don't know what type each instance will be, you could use a `List<Object>` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a collection. For example a `Set`

```
Set<TestLocal> set = new HashSet<TestLocal>();

for (..) {
  TestLocal t = new TestLocal();
  set.add(t);
}
```

Then you can iterate your instances:

```
for (TestLocal t : set) {
 // access each instance
}
```

---

If you want just one instance to be accessible outside, then simply define it outside:

```
TestLocal t = null;
for (..) {
  t = new TestLocal();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bozho!  -  I added more conidtions for my real life project: I need to dynamically create t's....

Comment: i'm looking for the data in a map to decide what class to use to create an instance. for example, in one map, I find type = 1 and start=1, then I create a Title instance (from iText library)....

Comment: well, how does that complicate things? Show some more code of yours.

Comment: Hi Bozho, yes, I just added the real program above: the for loop is looking at each map to decide whether to create a Chapter or Section instance....